# in PYTHON...How to Find the index for the PARTIAL elements in NESTED tuples

Tags: indexing, nested, tuples, partial

Here is my nested tuple list...Which means, Each tuple contains another two set of tuples inside each tuple.

```
 R22 =   [((13, 15, 1), (3, 8, 1)), ((13, 16, 1), (3, 11, 1)), ((13, 27, 1), (3, 32, 1)), ((13, 36, 1), (3, 44, 1)), ((13, 47, 1), (3, 46, 1)), ((15, 16, 1), (8, 11, 1)), ((15, 27, 1), (8, 32, 1)), ((15, 36, 1), (8, 44, 1)), ((15, 47, 1), (8, 46, 1)), ((16, 27, 1), (11, 32, 1)), ((16, 36, 1), (11, 44, 1)), ((16, 47, 1), (11, 46, 1)), ((27, 36, 1), (32, 44, 1)), ((27, 47, 1), (32, 46, 1)), ((36, 47, 1), (44, 46, 1))]
```

and now i need to find the index for the partial elements such as

```
FindeIndex('13, 15') and the expected result would be 0,0 and for (3, 11) the answer would be 1,1. and for (3,8) the expected answer would be 0,1. and so on.
```

PS: Please take note that i'm not trying to find the index for the whole tuple i'm taking only the first two PARTIAL elements in a NESTED tuple.

```
And what i tried is 

    print(R22.index('(13, 27)')) is not working and saying can't find in list.

    and i tried this way print(R22.index('(13, 27, 1), (3, 32, 1)')) also said not found.
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Oh forget to mention...Python. and just added